# sftp disabled, but have ssh access. How to mount?

Tags: linux, ssh, mount, remote, sftp

some lab computers at my university have sftp disabled. 
However, I have normal ssh access.
Obviously I don't have root permissions on these computers.

I need to transfer a fair amount of VHDL to/from these.
I could use, fx:

```
ssh user@lab1 cat file > local_copy
```

-and tarball it all up, but that is plain ugly. 
I would rather mount through sftp so I can use my own local editor, but given the circumstances...

And I belive that SSHFS (the FUSE module) depends on sftp... :/

Comment: Just found shfs but it seems rather old. No package for ubuntu.

Comment: Not sure what shfs is, but sshfs is under active development. Build source if no Ubuntu package.

Answer (score 3):

If sftp is merely missing, as opposed to actively forbidden (which I'm not sure is even possible if you have full command line access), obtain an `sftp-server` binary for the right architecture and version of OpenSSH, and specify its path when calling `sftp` or `sshfs`:

```
sftp -s /path/to/sftp-server user@lab1
sshfs -o sftp_server=/path/to/sftp-server user@lab1:/ /path/to/mount/point
```

If your local editor is Emacs, you don't need all that: [Tramp](http://www.gnu.org/software/tramp/) can use many different methods including [ssh](http://www.gnu.org/software/tramp/#Inline-methods) and [ssh+scp](http://www.gnu.org/software/tramp/#External-methods).

If you prefer to maintain a local copy of all the files, you can use [Unison](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/) (like rsync, but bidirectional) to keep them in synch.

Comment: Thanks for the `-o sftp_server`; I was consistently missing it in the docs until found here. :) Works for me in the *dropbear + openssh-sftp-server* combination.